# GCC Compile Error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3.lib

Tags: gcc, c, libraries

I'm trying to compile a little C-program using SQLite3. I've already included the Header-File and converted the .dll file into a .lib file.

The interesting thing is that on windows, gcc (CodeBlocks) can compile the source code without any problems. But under Debian (Raspberry Pi) I'm getting this error message: **/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3.lib**

The sqlite3.lib file is in the same folder as the main.c file I want to compile. (I have also tried to copy the .lib file to /usr/bin/ - no success)

And if I try to run the windows-compiled program on my raspberry, I get another error message...

Here's my source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sqlite3.h"

static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName);

int main(void){

    sqlite3 *db=NULL;
    int erg = 0;
    char *errMsg = NULL;

    erg = sqlite3_open("temp_values.db", &db);

    if (erg == 1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Fehler beim Oeffnen der DB!\n");
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else fprintf(stdout, "Database connection successful!\n");

    erg = sqlite3_exec(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_values (username TEXT, port TEXT, degrees INTEGER, humidity INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(username, port));", callback, 0, &errMsg);

    if (erg){
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", errMsg);
    }
    else fprintf(stdout, "Table check successful!\n");

    erg = sqlite3_exec(db, "INSERT INTO temp_values (username, port, degrees, humidity) VALUES ('root', '4', 24, 35);", callback, 0, &errMsg);

    if (erg){
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", errMsg);
    }
    else fprintf(stdout, "Inserted tuple successful!\n");

    sqlite3_close(db);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<argc; i++){
        printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");

    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;

}
```

I hope someone can help me ...

Comment: Do you have the sqlite-devel packages installed? On CentOS it's called sqlite-devel.x86_64

Comment: If the error is really ` /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3.lib` I suspect problems in your makefile (linux static libs have a .a extension.

Comment: Please post your build recipe, makefile or whatever. In the question, not the comments, please.

Comment: On Debian Jessie, you need `libsqlite3-dev`.

Comment: If you try link windows `.lib` file with  your code on linux, then this is expected result. You need sqlite compiled for OS/CPU. So you need three different instances of sqlite, for windows + x86, linux + x86 and linux + arm

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The most basic problem here is that you cannot take a binary file (a program,
object file, library) that you have built on one operating system (e.g. Windows) and expect
it work on another operating system (e.g. Linux). Binary file formats differ
between operating systems.

Windows executables and libraries are unrecognizable to Debian. So if you
have a program that uses the `sqlite3` library that you want to run on Debian,
you need to:

- Compile the source files on Debian to create Linux object files.
- Link the object files with an `sqlite3` library that has also been built for Linux.

A secondary problem is that, even if a Linux `sqlite3` library was called `sqlite3.lib`
(which it wouldn't be), and even if `sqlite3.lib` was in the current directory when
you tried to link your program, the linker option `-lsqlite3.lib` will not enable
the linker to find it (as you have discovered).

The [offical behaviour of the GNU linker option `-l`*foo*](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html)
is to make the linker search a given directory in its library search paths for
a file called *libfoo.a* (a static library) or *libfoo.so* (a dynamic library) and
to prefer *libfoo.so* if it finds both in the same directory. Hence, `-lsqlite3.lib`
asks the linker to find either `libsqlite3.lib.so` or `libsqlite3.lib.a`, neither of
which exists.

On Windows, you will find that `-lsqlite3.lib` works. That is because Windows
libraries do not follow the Linux convention that the *foo* static library
is *libfoo.a* and the *foo* dynamic library is *libfoo.so*. So the Windows port
of the GNU linker accepts Windows-style library names in the `-l` option, as [explained
here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use).

On Debian, the developer package of the `sqlite3` library is available from the
package manager as `libsqlite3-dev`. You can install it, as root, with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

After you have installed it, you can compile your program, say it is `main.c`, with the command:

```
gcc -Wall -c -o main.o main.c
```

Link it:

```
gcc -o prog main.o -lsqlite3
```

Run it:

```
$ ./prog
Database connection successful!
Table check successful!
Inserted tuple successful!
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked with installing the libsqlite3-dev package! And next time I want to use libraries, I'll know how to do it (either .a or .so). You're guys are great!

Comment: @MichaelGierer Welcome to Stackoverflow! If this answer has solved your problem you can [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the green check-mark. That's how you say "thanks".

Answer (score 8):

issue this in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

and window lib file does not work in linux